# Could not connect to database postgres pg_hba (OSX)

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, metasploit, createuser

So I'm trying to set up PostgreSQL to be used with metasploit on my Mac 10.9 Mavericks machine.  I'm trying to follow the instructions outlined on this page.  http://www.darkoperator.com/installing-metasploit-framewor/ and I got to the command:

```
createuser msf -P -h localhost
```

here is the result:

```
$ createuser msf -P -h localhost
Enter password for new role: 
Enter it again: 
createuser: could not connect to database postgres: FATAL:  no pg_hba.conf entry for host "127.0.0.1", user "myname", database "postgres", SSL off
```

I changed the part that says "myname" to that because I dont want to post my name on here.  I've searched the internet for a couple days for a solution to this and I'm pretty sure I need to edit pg_hba.conf.  Here is my pg_hba.conf file's contents:

```
 80 # TYPE  DATABASE    USER        CIDR-ADDRESS          METHOD
 81 
 82 # "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
 83 #local   all         all                               trust
 84 host     all         all        0.0.0.0/0             md5
 85 local   all         all                               md5
 86 # IPv4 local connections:
 87 host    all         all         127.0.0.1/32          md5
 88 # IPv6 local connections:
 89 host    all         all         ::1/128               md5
 90 
 91 # TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD
 92 #local   postgres        postgres                                trust
 93 #local   msf_db          msf_user                                trust
 94 # Allow replication connections from localhost, by a user with the
 95 # replication privilege.
 96 #local   replication     postgres                                trust
 97 #host    replication     postgres        127.0.0.1/32            trust
 98 #host    replication     postgres        ::1/128                 trust
```

Can you tell me what I need to add/remove(comment out) from this section to get postgresql up and running?

Let me know if you need any more info to help me learn how to solve this.  Thank you!!

EDIT 1:

I was told all I need to do is restart the database and this is what I get:

```
sh-3.2# pg_ctl stop -D /opt/local/var/db/postgresql93/defaultdb
pg_ctl: cannot be run as root
Please log in (using, e.g., "su") as the (unprivileged) user that will
own the server process.
```

I logged in as su to complete this...

EDIT 2:

I then tried to complete this using my default user and this is what I got (I am certain I typed the correct password for myself)

```
sxxx:~ sxxx$ createuser msf -P -h localhost
Enter password for new role: 
Enter it again: 
Password: 
createuser: could not connect to database postgres: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "sxxx"
```

EDIT 3:

Thanks to the help of some others I found out I need to log in to my postgres user to create this.  I'm still not able to complete this here is what I did:

```
Sxxx-MacBook-Pro:~ sxxx$ sudo su - postgres
Sxxx-MacBook-Pro:~ postgres$ createuser msf -P -h localhost
Enter password for new role: 
Enter it again: 
createuser: could not connect to database postgres: FATAL:  role "postgres" does not exist
```

which seems weird to me.

EDIT 4:

Miraculously I closed my terminal window and opened a new one and the same thing I had been doing this whole time worked:

```
Sxxx-MacBook-Pro:~ sxxx$ createuser msf -P -h localhost
Enter password for new role: 
Enter it again: 
Sxxx-MacBook-Pro:~ sxxx$ createdb -O msf msf -h localhost
Sxxx-MacBook-Pro:~ sxxx$
```

Comment: The first non-commented line of your pg_hba.conf already allows any connection from any IPv4 address, so you just have to make postgresql reload that file.

Comment: @DanielVérité how do I make PostgreSQL reload that file?

Comment: Basically with `pg_ctl reload` but the specifics depend on what postgres package you're using. If you simply restart postgres, this will also work.

Comment: @DanielVérité when i try to shut down the database I get an error. As well as when I try to restart it: See my edit:

Comment: Please read the instructions from the postgres package you installed on the basic stuff. [Several packages exist](http://www.postgresql.org/download/macosx/) and each of them has its own procedures when it comes to what user runs the commands and what directories they're in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check what user PostgreSQL is running as.  Usually this will be `pgsql` or `postgres`.  Run the `createuser` command as that user.

```
$ sudo su
# su postgres -c 'createuser msf -P -h localhost'
```

You probably don't need to touch the `pg_hba.conf` file.

Comment: _Usually this will be pgsql or postgres_:  not that usual with MacOS. Packages such as postgres.app or IIRC postgres for homebrew run under the desktop user.

Comment: You're right.  For some reason I have a postgres user on my laptop, but the homebrew recipe does indeed run it as the desktop user.  In other words: the original poster's problem should go away if he runs `createuser` as himself instead of root.

Comment: Except if using postgres packaged by entreprisedb or one of the others that actually use the `postgres` user.

Comment: Hey @DanielVérité I added a new edit. I think we are getting closer to solving this!

Comment: Hey @PhilipPaeps I think we are getting closer to fixing this.  I added an edit of what I got.

Comment: Your "EDIT 4" hits the nail on the head: as Daniel pointed out, PostgreSQL on Mac will often (but not always) run as the desktop user.  On your installation, you also have a postgres user, but it's apparently not empowered.